# max-height ignored when percentage padding defines element height

Tags: css

The `max-height` property value seems to be ignored when the inner padding is greater than the max-height value. For example, setting this class on an element causes the max-height to be ignored.

```
.max-height-ignored {
    height: 0; /* or auto, makes no difference */
    max-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rxavsupL/)

In my situation, It would be a pain to wrap the element to prevent overflow and was just wondering if there was a reason behind this not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The min/max width/height properties never take any other box dimensions into account, neither borders nor padding. They only constrain the used values of the `width` and `height` properties respectively. [Section 10 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) does not explicitly mention borders or padding in the prose for the min/max properties, but it does refer to the `width` and `height` properties, both of which refer to content dimensions.

If you set `height: 50px`, the element will still be constrained to a content height of 40px. The padding then extends from the content area.

Unfortunately, it appears `box-sizing: border-box` does not address this fully, at least not when the borders and/or padding are in excess of width and height.

While I can infer that this happens as a result of browsers following the spec, why the spec was *written* this way I cannot answer objectively. Given that padding and overflow clipping can work together, I don't think the reason for this behavior has anything to do with overflow.

Comment: This is an utterly ridiculous error in the design of CSS, as far as I can see.  Why does it matter if the padding exceeds available space?  We have clipping for a reason.  I've just spent literally *4 hours* trying to debug a random appearance of an additional scroll bar in the wrong place when a message appears that takes up too much space and therefore the available space shrinks to less than the total padding.  The padding which is in a box that is already displaying a scroll bar.

Answer (score 8):

It might be obvious, but as a work around, you might be able to limit the width of the **wrapper** using `max-width`. In my particular case, this required a `max-width: 50vh` ([`vh`: percentage of viewport height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)).