# maintain aspect ratio of div and also apply max-height and max-width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to maintain aspect ratio, but also limit the maximum size. The height doesn't seem to get the memo. Any idea why?

See this codepen:
https://codepen.io/timsim/pen/mmRLdq

My code:

```css
* {
  box-sixing: border-box;
}

#color-picker {
  width: 15%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="color-picker"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420434/max-height-ignored-when-percentage-padding-defines-element-height

Comment: Yeah it is.Sorry about tha

Comment: No problem.. Always do some research before posting =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you misspelt `box-sizing`, and second thing, if `padding` is greater than element's height, it will increase element's height no matter you are using `border-box` or `content-box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#color-picker {
  width: 15%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="color-picker"></div>
```